# How can i change the line color of an entry based on a condition in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

So i do some validations on my entries and i would like to change the color to red when the value is invalid.

Is there a way to do this in xamarin right now ?

I know that there's renderer to change the color permanently but i just want to change it based on a condition and leave it black when everything is ok.

Thank you.

Comment: The renderer doesn't have to do it permanently, it can be set to be done on certain events. If you're using the material renderer and it meets your requirements, you can just change the text color. With the visual material renderer the underline matches the text color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite `OnElementPropertyChanged` method in your CustomRenderer to achieve this.

For example:

for **Android**:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(UnderLineEntry))]
namespace EntryCa.Droid
{
  class UnderLineEntry : EntryRenderer
  {
    public UnderLineEntry(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (Control.Text.Length > 6)  //this is your condition(For example, here is the length of the text content)
            {
                Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            }
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

the ios is the similar to Android,also change it in the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method,if you want i could give you an example.

for **ios**.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace EntryCa.iOS
{
  public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
  {
    private CALayer _line;

   public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

        _line = new CALayer
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor,
            Frame = new CGRect(0, Frame.Height, Frame.Width, 1f)
        };

        Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_line);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (Control.Text.Length > 6)
            {
                _line.RemoveFromSuperLayer();
                _line = new CALayer
                {
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor,
                    Frame = new CGRect(0, Frame.Height, Frame.Width, 1f)
                };

                Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_line);
            }
            else
            {
                _line.RemoveFromSuperLayer();
                _line = new CALayer
                {
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor,
                    Frame = new CGRect(0, Frame.Height, Frame.Width, 1f)
                };

                Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_line);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will i be able to use this if i do my validaiton with FluentValidation ? Cause i have some validations made in the code behind  of my xaml so it i will work but the rest of my validations are done in the ViewModel and i am using FluentValidaiton. Thanks

Comment: Zhu Also, could i have the iOS version of this please ? Thanks :)

Comment: @codetime ok,i will give you the codes for ios.(but i haven't tested it yet).

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know if theres a way to do it like i explained in my first comment ? Thanks

Comment: Ok because, i have some validation that is not made in the code behind also ( with fluent validation)  so there's no way to change the line color if the validation is not done in the code behind right ?

Comment: @codetime You mean you will get some  validation results from fluent validation ？If so, you might want to customize an entry and add a property to see if you need to change the color of the line，then use the same method like above.

Answer (score 0):

To change the line, have to use a custom renderer [like this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180799/change-the-colour-of-the-underline-in-an-entry-when-pressed).

Or just hide the line in the custom renderer and fake a line on the page, then you can control the color by [Data trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers).

Alternatively, what about adding a frame or changing the background color instead of the entry.

Comment: he specifically asked about the underline color, not the text color

Comment: Thx Jason. Sorry about my reading. Edited the answer.